# In vue.js, how can I render a list as element attributes, not as multiple elements

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I can't seem to find a functionality similar to `v-for`, but for attributes.

I'd like something like:

```
<div><data-attrs v-for="item in myattrlist">data-{{item.name}}="{{item.value}}"></data-attrs></div>
```

which would then render to

```
<div data-name1="value1" data-name2="value2"></div>
```

My search-fu is insufficient to find how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object to `v-bind` and the attribtues will be assigned from the object,

Example from [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind):

```js
<!-- binding an object of attributes -->
<div v-bind="{ id: someProp, 'other-attr': otherProp }"></div>
```

In your case it would be something like this,

```
<div v-bind="myattrlist.reduce((attrObj, attr) => ({...attrObj, ['data-' + attr.key]: attr.value}), {})"></div>
```

Though I'd suggest creating the `attrObj` in the `data()` method rather than in the template

Comment: Thanks for amending. Initially I had no idea how to make it work in my code :)